# Can't add a .bin.gz file as embedded resource

Tags: c#, .net-core, embedded-resource

If I include a .bin.gz file in a DLL as an embedded resource, it doesn't show up in the Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames() list, and cannot be loaded with Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(). If I rename the same file to anything else, it does show up.

The .bin.gz file shows up in .csproj. I'm building a .NET Core 2.2 class library.

What's going on? Is there some kind of filter by file type that prevents certain types from being embedded?

EDIT: On further inspection. It appears that the .bin.gz resources are placed in a different .dll named [AssemblyName].resources.dll, which is placed in a "bin" folder next to the [AssemblyName].dll. Why is this and why does this not happen with other files?